# Setting value based on different table in NHibernate query

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate, and have problems with this query... I have a class Item which I want to fetch using its Id. All fine. However, I also want a bool property on the Item class to be set to true if some other condition is set. Specifically this property is named IsMarked, telling if the Item is marked/stared/flagged for the user that requested it, and this information is set on a table giving the relation between Item and User.

Currently I'm fetching the Item, and then finding the reference - updating the property to true if the reference could be found. Can I do this in one query instead?

```
var item = Session.Get<Item>(itemId);

var flaggedResult = Session.CreateCriteria<ItemWithUserFlag>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("User.Id", userId))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Item", item))
    .List<ItemWithUserFlag>();

if (flaggedResult.Count > 0)
    item.IsMarked = true; 

return item;
```

Comment: How are your classes mapped? Is there a many-to-many releation between User and Item?

Comment: I am using Fluent for the mappings. There is a many-to-many relation represented in a separate class ItemWithUserFlag. User does not have a direct relation to Item, and Item does not have a direct relation to User. ItemWithUserFlag has a References set to User and to Item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using `formula` along with `filter` in your property mapping:

```
<property name="IsMarked" formula="(select count(*) from ItemWithUserFlag where ItemWithUserFlag.ItemId = ItemId and ItemWithUserFlag.UserId = :UserFilter.userId)" />
```

And filter def:

```
<filter-def name="UserFilter">
    <filter-param name="userId" type="Int32"/>
</filter-def>
```

That will result in something like

```
SELECT Item.*, (select count(*) from ItemWithUserFlag where ItemWithUserFlag.ItemId = Item.ItemId and ItemWithUserFlag.UserId = ?) AS IsMarked FROM Item
```

As long as IsMarked is defined as `bool`, if `count(*)` returns `0` it will be converted to `false` and if anything `> 0` it will be converted to `true`.

EDIT: Fluent representation

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        /// ... whatever
        Map(x => x.IsMarked).Formula("(select count(*) from ItemWithUserFlag where ItemWithUserFlag.ItemId = ItemId and ItemWithUserFlag.UserId = :UserFilter.userId)");
    }
}

public class UserFilter : FilterDefinition
{
    public UserFilter()
    {
        WithName("UserFilter")
            .AddParameter("userId", NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.Int32);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! Haven't tested yet, but sounds like this would work. Problem in my case is that I use FluentNhibernate for the mappings. Dunno if I can define some mappings i xml at the same time, or if the same can be expressed in Fluent. So, there is no way to achieve this directly in the query?

Comment: @stiank81 About achieving this in query: I believe there is not any way. Logically, what you want is not a restriction or what, but a calculated column, so I think it must be done via mappings. But, I'm not such an expert on nHibernate and thus I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: Thx for the edit! Not able to test right now, but will get back to you.